# Can I still update or create items in a table that has Azure mobile services EntityData with entity framework or SQL?

Tags: entity-framework, azure, azure-mobile-services

I have an azure mobile services and all the tables inherit from EntityData (to enable offline sync), which means they have system columns created automatically such as:

- CreatedAt UpdatedAt Deleted

If I try to update or insert to this tables, can I still do it with just entity framework or plain SQL, or do I now have to do it all through the mobile service.

I'm somehow confused with the whole purpose of the EntityData and what it means. Cause I want an application that would be able to use offline sync, but still access data from a webpage.

Answer (score 0):

The Azure Mobile Services SDK makes it very easy to perform CRUD operations on your tables but that doesn't mean you can't still access the tables using entity framework or just plain SQL.

Remember the Azure Mobile Services SDK supports both offline and online operations, but if you need to use the same Azure mobile services database with another client application, then you would have to get the SQL database connection string and connection information from the Azure Mobile services dashboard. With both information, your client app can use Entity framework or plain SQL queries to interact with the tables.